# Can I use different subjects like the following in two clauses?

Tags: grammar, clauses

I know I can use

```
When I opened the envelope, I found two letters within it.
```

However, I wish to go for the following, if it is correct

```
When I opened the envelope, two letters showed up.
```

> Can the second sentence be deemed as correct?

Comment: Both are grammatically correct, but the second one sounds weird. Why the preference?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've really no preference here. Just wanted to know if I can go for the second expression if need be.